# 403 Error while creating storage account in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, amazon-iam, subscription

I was trying to access the CLI in azure. I wanted to execute the script in Power shell CLI. But I'm not able to create a storage account for PowerShell in azure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get the error that you are not authorized to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope of <s>storage account</s> because you don't have the relevant permissions on the <s>Storage Account.</s>

You either need to have <s>"Contributor"</s>  permissions to create & manage storage account or related resources. More details of the azure RBAC roles in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)

**edit:**

as  4c74356b41  mentioned in the comment, you need read role and scope should be resource group.

Comment: Im able to create resources like virtual machines, data factory etc under this resource group and subscription. do i need to add my account in the IAM of subscrition?

Comment: Check your role permission for this particular resource cloud shell storage

Comment: how is this upvoted? this clearly says he needs read, not write, so its not contributor, but reader. also, not scope of storage account, but scope of resource group

Comment: thanks for that, you are correct. OP has upvoted i guess

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly indicates that you don’t have “read” permission on “cloud-shell-storage-westeurope” resource group.

Please ask your administrator to grant you proper permission on this resource group.

Comment: alternatively, you can just follow ui prompts and specify another resource group for cli storage (or just specify existing storage to use for your cli permanent storage)

Answer (score 1):

if this happens during a lab session (as for me):
check the region and chose "US West"

the instruction don't tell about. for me europe was pre-selected.